# How to change frameserver file format

Tags: rendering

If you set the output to frame server you will get images at localhost:8080/images/ppm/1.ppm

is it possible to change the format from ppm to open exr for example ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible right now.

The frame server is implemented in [`source/blender/blenkernel/intern/writeframeserver.c`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/e92f235283071c13759bc4e6e861e4e938985307:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/writeframeserver.c#l204) .As of 2.78c, Blender will only respond with a PPM image, but it looks like other formats can be easily added.